# Square brackets on Swedish Keyboard - MacBook Pro with Catalina MacOs

Tags: macos, keyboard

Each time I need to use square brackets '[]' I need to find them somewhere else and Copy & Paste them. I could add an extra language to my keyboard and switch languages every time I need to use square brackets but it would be nice to find simpler way that works with the Swedish keyboard.

I use Catalina MacOS and I've tried both using the keyboard of my MacBook Pro and and external Logitech keyboard but so far no success.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to find anything like this is from the Keyboard Viewer, available as an option for the menu bar in System Prefs > Keyboard > Input sources [or also in that pref itself]

Finding the Swedish layout in that panel shows `[` & `]` on Opt 8 & 9 respectively.

[image]